# Find original Point within image after rotation c#

Tags: c#, image, rotation, point

Below is a picture that illustrates what i am trying to do.

http://tinypic.com/r/nvbehh/5

I am rotating an image in c# (the white rectangle). 
The problem is that i need to place the green square (another image) on the same point relative to the rectangle regardless of rotation. The green square cannot be rotated with the rectangle.

As you can see after rotation of the white rectangle i end up with a different size canvas each time.

I am trying to find the exact point to place the green square after the new rotated image is created.

OK below is some code that rotates the image and puts the dot in the correct place.
Now the issue is that if i apply the transformations in the RotateImage method i see all of the rectagle but obviously my red dot is in the wrong spot. 
I should stress i need to know the point of the dot not just place it in the right spot.

```
public class IconController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Icon/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ////Icon/Icon?connected=true&heading=320&type=logo45
    public ActionResult Icon(bool connected, float heading, string type)
    {
        var dir = Server.MapPath("/images");
        //RED SQUARE IM TRYING TO PLACE ON THE BLUE RECTANGLE.
        var path = Path.Combine(dir, "mapicons/center.png");

        //GREEN RECTANGLE WITH FIXED YELLOW (Actual center) AND BLUE (point im really trying to find)
        var path2 = Path.Combine(dir, "mapicons/connected-marker.png");

        Image innerIcon = Image.FromFile(path);
        Image marker = Image.FromFile(path2);

        using (marker)
        {

            Point orginalCenter = new Point((marker.Width / 2), (marker.Height / 2));
            Bitmap markerbitmap = RotateImage(new Bitmap(marker), heading);

            marker = (Image)markerbitmap;
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(marker.Width, marker.Height))
            {
                using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    PointF newCenter = RotatePoint(orginalCenter, 80, 120, heading, marker.Width, marker.Height);
                    canvas.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                    canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    canvas.DrawImage(marker, new Rectangle(0, 0, marker.Width, marker.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, marker.Width, marker.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    canvas.DrawImage(innerIcon, newCenter.X - (innerIcon.Width / 2), newCenter.Y - (innerIcon.Height / 2));

                    canvas.Save();
                }
                try
                {
                    bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(dir, "result.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
                    path = Path.Combine(dir, "result.png");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }


        return base.File(path, "image/png");
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap b, float Angle)
    {
        // The original bitmap needs to be drawn onto a new bitmap which will probably be bigger 
        // because the corners of the original will move outside the original rectangle.
        // An easy way (OK slightly 'brute force') is to calculate the new bounding box is to calculate the positions of the 
        // corners after rotation and get the difference between the maximum and minimum x and y coordinates.
        float wOver2 = b.Width / 2.0F;
        float hOver2 = b.Height / 2.0F;
        float radians = -(float)(Angle / 180.0 * Math.PI);
        // Get the coordinates of the corners, taking the origin to be the centre of the bitmap.
        PointF[] corners = new PointF[]{
        new PointF(-wOver2, -hOver2),
        new PointF(+wOver2, -hOver2),
        new PointF(+wOver2, +hOver2),
        new PointF(-wOver2, +hOver2)
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            PointF p = corners[i];
            PointF newP = new PointF((float)(p.X * Math.Cos(radians) - p.Y * Math.Sin(radians)), (float)(p.X * Math.Sin(radians) + p.Y * Math.Cos(radians)));
            corners[i] = newP;
        }

        // Find the min and max x and y coordinates.
        float minX = corners[0].X;
        float maxX = minX;
        float minY = corners[0].Y;
        float maxY = minY;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            PointF p = corners[i];
            minX = Math.Min(minX, p.X);
            maxX = Math.Max(maxX, p.X);
            minY = Math.Min(minY, p.Y);
            maxY = Math.Max(maxY, p.Y);
        }

        // Get the size of the new bitmap.
        SizeF newSize = new SizeF(maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
        // ...and create it.
        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap((int)Math.Ceiling(newSize.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(newSize.Height));
        // Now draw the old bitmap on it.
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap))
        {
            g.TranslateTransform(newSize.Width / 2.0f, newSize.Height / 2.0f);
            g.RotateTransform(Angle);

        g.TranslateTransform(-b.Width / 2.0f, -b.Height / 2.0f);

            g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
        }

        return returnBitmap;
    }


    public static Point RotatePoint(Point pointToRotate, Point centerPoint, double angleInDegrees)
    {
        double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
        double cosTheta = Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
        double sinTheta = Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

        Point pt = new Point();
        pt.X = (int)(cosTheta * (pointToRotate.X-centerPoint.X) - sinTheta * (pointToRotate.Y-centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X);

        pt.Y = (int)(sinTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) + cosTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y);
        //p'y = sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy

        return pt;

    }
}
```

So now i need to be able to uncomment the TranslateTransform in the RotateImage method so that i see the correct rectangle and modify the RotatePoint method so i get the correct new location

Comment: You will need to do math, that matches the rotation. Maybe Google "rotate rectangle algorithm". You are looking for math that given XY positions of 4 corners, applies a rotation. I stress that you are looking for MATH, not for calls into a GUI. Something using Sin() and Cos(). Then you will need to figure out how this relates to your visual image.

Comment: OK The above does intended now. @ToolmakerSteve thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Not sure how to mark this as answered etc

Comment: Glad that helped.  You can write an answer to your own question ("Answer Your Question" button), and are encouraged to do so, so that people know it has been answered. Then mark that as the answer.  If you've already corrected it in the question, then you might show "before" and "after" in the answer, to indicate what you had been missing originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working controller.
    public class IconController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Icon/

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ////Icon/Icon?connected=true&heading=320&type=logo45
    public ActionResult Icon(bool connected, float heading, string type)
    {
        var dir = Server.MapPath("/images");
        //RED SQUARE IM TRYING TO PLACE ON THE BLUE RECTANGLE.
        var path = Path.Combine(dir, "mapicons/center.png");

        //GREEN RECTANGLE WITH FIXED YELLOW (Actual center) AND BLUE (point im really trying to find)
        var path2 = Path.Combine(dir, "mapicons/connected-marker.png");

        Image innerIcon = Image.FromFile(path);
        Image marker = Image.FromFile(path2);

        using (marker)
        {

            Point orginalCenter = new Point((marker.Width / 2), (marker.Height / 2));
            Bitmap markerbitmap = RotateImage(new Bitmap(marker), heading);

            marker = (Image)markerbitmap;
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(marker.Width, marker.Height))
            {
                using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    PointF newCenter = RotatePoint(orginalCenter, 80, 120, heading, marker.Width, marker.Height);
                    canvas.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                    canvas.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    canvas.DrawImage(marker, new Rectangle(0, 0, marker.Width, marker.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, marker.Width, marker.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    canvas.DrawImage(innerIcon, newCenter.X - (innerIcon.Width / 2), newCenter.Y - (innerIcon.Height / 2));

                    canvas.Save();
                }
                try
                {
                    bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(dir, "result.png"), ImageFormat.Png);
                    path = Path.Combine(dir, "result.png");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }


        return base.File(path, "image/png");
    }

    public static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap b, float Angle)
    {
        // The original bitmap needs to be drawn onto a new bitmap which will probably be bigger 
        // because the corners of the original will move outside the original rectangle.
        // An easy way (OK slightly 'brute force') is to calculate the new bounding box is to calculate the positions of the 
        // corners after rotation and get the difference between the maximum and minimum x and y coordinates.
        float wOver2 = b.Width / 2.0F;
        float hOver2 = b.Height / 2.0F;
        float radians = -(float)(Angle / 180.0 * Math.PI);
        // Get the coordinates of the corners, taking the origin to be the centre of the bitmap.
        PointF[] corners = new PointF[]{
        new PointF(-wOver2, -hOver2),
        new PointF(+wOver2, -hOver2),
        new PointF(+wOver2, +hOver2),
        new PointF(-wOver2, +hOver2)
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            PointF p = corners[i];
            PointF newP = new PointF((float)(p.X * Math.Cos(radians) - p.Y * Math.Sin(radians)), (float)(p.X * Math.Sin(radians) + p.Y * Math.Cos(radians)));
            corners[i] = newP;
        }

        // Find the min and max x and y coordinates.
        float minX = corners[0].X;
        float maxX = minX;
        float minY = corners[0].Y;
        float maxY = minY;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            PointF p = corners[i];
            minX = Math.Min(minX, p.X);
            maxX = Math.Max(maxX, p.X);
            minY = Math.Min(minY, p.Y);
            maxY = Math.Max(maxY, p.Y);
        }

        // Get the size of the new bitmap.
        SizeF newSize = new SizeF(maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
        // ...and create it.
        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap((int)Math.Ceiling(newSize.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(newSize.Height));
        // Now draw the old bitmap on it.
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap))
        {
            g.TranslateTransform(newSize.Width / 2.0f, newSize.Height / 2.0f);
            g.RotateTransform(Angle);

        g.TranslateTransform(-b.Width / 2.0f, -b.Height / 2.0f);

            g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
        }

        return returnBitmap;
    }


    public static Point RotatePoint(Point pointToRotate, Point centerPoint, double angleInDegrees)
    {
        double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
        double cosTheta = Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
        double sinTheta = Math.Sin(angleInRadians);

        Point pt = new Point();
        pt.X = (int)(cosTheta * (pointToRotate.X-centerPoint.X) - sinTheta * (pointToRotate.Y-centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X);

        pt.Y = (int)(sinTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) + cosTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y);
        //p'y = sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy

        return pt;

    }
}
```